# How to derive OLS estimates of beta by minimizing the error sum of squares?

Tags: regression, distributions, self-study, residuals

For the model: $Y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1X_i+\epsilon_i, \epsilon_i \sim^{iid} N(0,\sigma^2)$ for $i=1,...,n.$ Let $X_i >0$ and $\sigma^2_i=\sigma^2X_i$. $\tilde{Q}(\beta)=\sum^{n}_{i=1}\sigma_{i}^{-2}\{Y_{i}-(\beta_0+\beta_1X_{i})\}^2$ is the weighted error sum of squares.

- Let $\hat\beta=(\beta_0,\beta_1)^T$ denote the OLS estimators of the model.
- Let $Y=(Y_1, ..., Y_n)$ denote the response variables.
- $X = n\times2$ design matrix where the first column is 1's.
- $\beta = (\beta_0, \beta_1)^T$ be the regression coefficients.

The error sum of squares is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\{Y_{i}-(\beta_0+\beta_1X_{i})\}$. I a, attempting to derive the OLS estimates of $\beta$ by minimizing the error sum of squares. I did it below, there is another part of this question that asks me to then based on the derived estimates of $\beta$ that I obtain I should find the distribution of $\hat\beta$ and the variance of $\hat\epsilon_i$ given that $\hat\epsilon=(\hat\epsilon_1,..\hat\epsilon_n)^T$ for $i=1,...,n.$

To derive the OLS of beta, I did the following:

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\{Y_{i}-(\beta_0+\beta_1X_{i})\} = ||(Y-X\beta)||^2$. So, we must solve $argmin_{\beta}||(Y-X\beta)||^{2} \rightarrow \beta_{OLS} = (X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}Y$. I am a bit confused as to how I can use this to find the distribution of $\hat\beta$ and the variance of $\epsilon_i$.

**Update**
Using $Y$ to express $\hat\beta$. I got: Since $\hat\beta = (X^{T}X)^{-1} X^{T}Y = X^{T}X)^{-1} X^{T} XB + \epsilon_{i}$.The mean of $\hat\beta = E[\beta\hat] = E[(X^{T}X)^{-1} X^{T} XB + \epsilon_{i}] = \beta$, and $Var[\hat\beta] = Var[(X^{T}X)^{-1} X^{T} XB + \epsilon_{i}] = \sigma^2 (X^{T}X)^{-1}$ So, $\hat\beta \sim N(\beta, \sigma^2 (X^{T}X)^{-1})$.

Comment: Since $Y$ is expressed in terms of the $\varepsilon_i$ at the start of your post, try using that to express $\hat{\beta}$ as a function of the $\varepsilon_i$. It may help to write the $\varepsilon_i$ as a vector